# How to change Hash values?

Tags: ruby, syntax, hash

I'd like to replace each `value` in a hash with `value.some_method`.

For example, for given a simple hash:

```
{"a" => "b", "c" => "d"}`
```

every value should be `.upcase`d, so it looks like:

```
{"a" => "B", "c" => "D"}
```

I tried `#collect` and `#map` but always just get arrays back. Is there an elegant way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Damn, I forgot: The hash is in an instance variable which should not be changed. I need a new hash with the changed values, but would prefer not to define that variable explicitly and then loop over the hash filling it. Something like:

```
new_hash = hash.magic{ ... }
```

Answer (score 236, accepted):

```
my_hash.each { |k, v| my_hash[k] = v.upcase }
```

or, if you'd prefer to do it non-destructively, and return a new hash instead of modifying `my_hash`:

```
a_new_hash = my_hash.inject({}) { |h, (k, v)| h[k] = v.upcase; h }
```

This last version has the added benefit that you could transform the keys too.

Comment: The first suggestion is not appropriate; modifying an enumerable element while iterating leads to undefined behavior - this is valid in other languages also.

Here's a reply from Matz (he replies to an example using an Array, but the answer is generic): http://j.mp/tPOh2U

Comment: @Marcus I agree that in general such modification should be avoided. But in this case it's probably safe, because the modification doesn't change future iterations. Now if another key (that wasn't the one passed to the block) was assigned, then there would be trouble.

Comment: @Adam @kch `each_with_object` is a more convenient version of `inject` when you don't want to end the block with the hash: `my_hash.each_with_object({}) {|(k, v), h| h[k] = v.upcase }`

Comment: There is also a very neat syntax to convert a list of pairs into a hash, so you can write `a_new_hash = Hash[ my_hash.map { |k, v| [k, v.upcase] } ]`

Comment: with Ruby 2 you can write `.to_h`

Comment: See  @potashin 's answer below for a better, modern solution.

Answer (score 135):

Since **`ruby 2.4.0`** you can use native [`Hash#transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) method:

```
hash = {"a" => "b", "c" => "d"}
new_hash = hash.transform_values(&:upcase)
# => {"a" => "B", "c" => "D"}
```

There is also destructive [`Hash#transform_values!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values-21) version.

Comment: great, it also comes with rails 4.2.1
https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/Hash/transform_values

Answer (score 36):

You can collect the values, and convert it from Array to Hash again.

Like this:

```
config = Hash[ config.collect {|k,v| [k, v.upcase] } ]
```

Answer (score 25):

This will do it:

```
my_hash.each_with_object({}) { |(key, value), hash| hash[key] = value.upcase }
```

As opposed to `inject` the advantage is that you are in no need to return the hash again inside the block.

Comment: I like that this method does not modify the original hash.

Answer (score 12):

There's a method for that in *ActiveSupport* v4.2.0. It's called [`transform_values`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/transform_values.rb) and basically just executes a block for each key-value-pair.

Since they're doing it with a `each` I think there's no better way than to loop through.

```rb
hash = {sample: 'gach'}

result = {}
hash.each do |key, value|
  result[key] = do_stuff(value)
end
```

**Update:**

Since Ruby 2.4.0 you can natively use [`#transform_values`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) and [`#transform_values!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values-21).

Answer (score 10):

Try this function:

```
h = {"a" => "b", "c" => "d"}
h.each{|i,j| j.upcase!} # now contains {"a" => "B", "c" => "D"}.
```

Comment: that's good, but it should be noted that it only works for when j has a destructive method that acts unto itself. So it can't handle the general value.some_method case.

Comment: Good point, and with his update, your second solution (non-destructive) is the best.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to go a step further and do this on a nested hash. Certainly this happens a fair amount with Rails projects.

Here's some code to ensure a params hash is in UTF-8:

```
  def convert_hash hash
    hash.inject({}) do |h,(k,v)|
      if v.kind_of? String
        h[k] = to_utf8(v) 
      else
        h[k] = convert_hash(v)
      end
      h
    end      
  end    

  # Iconv UTF-8 helper
  # Converts strings into valid UTF-8
  #
  # @param [String] untrusted_string the string to convert to UTF-8
  # @return [String] your string in UTF-8
  def to_utf8 untrusted_string=""
    ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
    ic.iconv(untrusted_string + ' ')[0..-2]
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I do something like this:

> new_hash = Hash[*original_hash.collect{|key,value| [key,value + 1]}.flatten]

This provides you with the facilities to transform the key or value via any expression also (and it's non-destructive, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has the `tap` method ([1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Object.html#method-i-tap), [1.9.3](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) and [2.1.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-tap)) that's very useful for stuff like this.

```
original_hash = { :a => 'a', :b => 'b' }
original_hash.clone.tap{ |h| h.each{ |k,v| h[k] = v.upcase } }
# => {:a=>"A", :b=>"B"}
original_hash # => {:a=>"a", :b=>"b"}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Rails-specific**

In case someone only needs to call `to_s` method to each of the values and is not using Rails 4.2 ( which includes `transform_values` method [link](http://www.justinweiss.com/blog/2014/08/25/the-lesser-known-features-in-rails-4-dot-2/)), you can do the following:

```
original_hash = { :a => 'a', :b => BigDecimal('23.4') }
#=> {:a=>"a", :b=>#<BigDecimal:5c03a00,'0.234E2',18(18)>}
JSON(original_hash.to_json)
#=> {"a"=>"a", "b"=>"23.4"}
```

*Note: The use of 'json' library is required.*

*Note 2: This will turn keys into strings as well*

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the values are strings, you can call the [replace](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/String.html#method-i-replace) method on them while in the cycle: this way you will change the value.

Altohugh this is limited to the case in which the values are strings and hence doesn't answer the question fully, I thought it can be useful to someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
new_hash = old_hash.merge(old_hash) do |_key, value, _value|
             value.upcase
           end

# old_hash = {"a" => "b", "c" => "d"}
# new_hash = {"a" => "B", "c" => "D"}
```

Comment: Is this efficient?