# Parsing a date string in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date, datetime, date-format, date-formatting

Currently I'm implementing a feature and using an external API. The API returns the following structure

```
{"StartDate"=>"/Date(1532563200000+0000)/", "ExpirationDate"=>"/Date(1564099200000+0000)/"}
```

I'm not sure how to parse `StartDate` and `ExpirationDate` to get their values in Ruby Time Format.

Any feedback welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Time.zone.at` to parse a timestamp in seconds.

```
response = {"StartDate"=>"/Date(1532563200000+0000)/", "ExpirationDate"=>"/Date(1564099200000+0000)/"}

start_date = Time.zone.at(response['StartDate'][6..15].to_i)
#=> Wed, 25 Jul 2018 20:00:00 EDT -04:00

expiration_date = Time.zone.at(response['ExpirationDate'][6..15].to_i)
#=> Thu, 25 Jul 2019 20:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Another of many way for Ruby in general

```
require 'date'
response.transform_values! { |date| Time.at(date[6..15].to_i).utc.to_datetime }
```

For Ruby versions not supporting `transform_values`:

```
response.inject({}) { |h, (k, v)| h[k] = Time.at(v[6..15].to_i).utc.to_datetime; h }
```

Thanks to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/812551

Comment: Note that you can use `transform_values!` method only if you're on Ruby 2.4+

Comment: Oops, I omitted it. Edited. Thanks @JohnBaker!